What does "measurable with respect to a partition" mean?
I am reading a paper. It defines the following things. $\Omega$ is a finite set of states and $S$ is the set of outcomes. An outcome function $F$ is a mapping from $\Omega$ to $S$. $P$ is a distribution over $\Omega$. $\Pi$ is a partition of $\Omega$. The authors require $F$ to be "measurable with respect to $\Pi$". I guess they mean "measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\Pi$". How does this $\sigma$-algebra look like?  (I don't know how to figure out the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains every set in $\Pi$)
The authors use a feature of $F$: for all $x$ and $y$ in the same cell of $\Pi$, $F(x)=F(y)$. Is this feature implied by the measurability condition?

Is it possible to link the paper? Or at least, can you say what $S$ is, because this is important to deduce this feature. (For example, if it was possible that $S = \Omega$, then this feature is not true). I am guessing that $S$ has (at least) the property that for any two distinct points in $S$, there is a measurable set containing one point but not the other. You should try to show that a set lies in the sigma-algebra generated by $\Pi$ iff that set is a union of parts in $\Pi$.

@IzaakvanDongen When they initially define $S$, no details are given. Then they say it only contains two elements. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053109000210

I think your guess "measurable with respect to $\sigma(\Pi)$" is the only reasonable interpretation here. I also assume that the output space of the function $F:\Omega\rightarrow S$ has a sigma algebra that contains all single element subsets of $S$.

Define $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ as the set of positive integers.
Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set. Let $\Pi = \{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable collection of disjoint subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i=\Omega$. The case when $\Pi$ contains only a finite number of nonempty subsets can be treated by defining $A_i=\phi$ for $i>k$, where $k$ is some positive integer and $\phi$ is the empty set.
Claim: $\sigma(\Pi)$ is the collection of all sets of the type $\cup_{i\in I} A_i$ for all $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ (including $I=\phi$).
Proof: It is straightforward to show this collection is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$ that contains all sets $A_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$. To show it is the smallest such, note that any sigma algebra on $\Omega$ that contains all sets $A_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ must also contain all unions of these sets (these are necessarily countable unions because there are only countably many sets to take unions of), and so must contain all sets of the form $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ for each $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. $\Box$

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sigma algebra on $S$ that contains all single element sets, that is
$$ \{a\} \in \mathcal{G} \quad \forall a \in S$$
Let $F:\Omega\rightarrow S$ be a function that is measurable with respect to $(\Omega, \sigma(\Pi))$ and $(S, \mathcal{G})$.
Claim: Fix $i \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x, y \in A_i$ then $F(x)=F(y)$.
Proof: Define $a=F(x)$. Then $a\in S$ and $\{a\} \in \mathcal{G}$.  Since $F$ is measurable we have
$$ \{t \in \Omega : F(t) \in \{a\}\} \in \sigma(\Pi)$$
Thus, there is a set $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\{t \in \Omega : F(t) \in \{a\}\}=\cup_{j \in I} A_j$$
Since $F(x)=a$ we know $x \in \cup_{j \in I} A_j$. Since $y$ is in the same $A_i$ set as $x$, we know $y \in \cup_{j \in I} A_j$ and so $F(y)=a$. $\Box$

The requirement that $\mathcal{G}$ contains all single element subsets of $S$ is needed. For example, if this is violated we can have $\mathcal{G}={\phi, S}$, and then all functions $F:\Omega\rightarrow S$ are measurable with respect to $(\Omega, \sigma(\Pi))$ and $(S, \mathcal{G})$, including functions that allow  $F(x)\neq F(y)$ when $x,y\in A_i$.

Thanks! I think the idea here is that if the sigma-algebra on $S$ does not contain enough elements, then the measurability of $F$ is not very restrictive, in other words, $F$ will not have some desirable properties.

Yeah. But I’ve only seen people use sigma algebras on the output space that include all single -element sets. That way you can measure useful sets.
